# How to see process created by specific user in Unix/linux

Tags: linux, process, ps

I want to see list  of  process created by specific user or group of user in Linux
Can I do it using `ps` command or is there any other command to achieve this?

Comment: `ps -u username`. Most commands have a manual page which you can read with `man the-command`.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

To view only the processes owned by a specific user, use the following command:

```
top -U [username]
```

Replace the [username] with the required username

If you want to use ps then

```
ps -u [username]
```

OR

```
 ps -ef | grep <username>
```

OR

```
ps -efl | grep <username>
```

for the extended listing

**Check out the man ps page for options**

Another alternative is to use pstree wchich prints the process tree of the user

```
pstree <username or pid>
```

Comment: All ` ... | grep <username>` solutions don't work if you have two usernames which are longer than N chars. In my case N is 6.

Comment: Note: I got an error for `top -U [username]`, and `top -u [username]` worked for me instead. Debian 9. So if anybody else gets an error with the -U form, try the lowercase.

Comment: Note: On FreeBSD it is `ps -U <username>` (notice the capital `U`)

Answer (score 8):

try this one

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -u <username>)
```

Comment: How is this better than `ps -u <username>`, as mentioned in the existing answer (or `ps -fu <username>` if you want process details)?

Comment: ps -u doesn't provide full process details, but ps -fu <username> does. Agree ps -fu is a best solution

Comment: `pgrep -u <username> | xargs ps u` shows even more process details.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `-e` (show all processes) overrides `-u` and makes it be ignored.

I was passing `-e` all the time without knowing what the option does, because I usually used `ps -ef`, and that made `-u` not work.

So if you want full listing you can keep the `-f`:

```
ps -fu USERNAME
```

Tested on Ubuntu 22.10,