# Output of processes and specific users with adding some text

Tags: process

I have tried to output processes for  specific user but with adding some text.
I can do like it is described in this answer [How to see process created by specific user in Unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85466/how-to-see-process-created-by-specific-user-in-unix-linux) but I don't know how to add some words in my output. For example I want to get something like this:

user "some word" PID

When I use `ps -ef | grep user` I get only user with a lot of options. What am i going to do to get my example `user "some word" PID` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear ... suppose you want to make the list of all processes of the root user, using the command `awk` we'll print only the column of PID and the arbitrary text:

```
export USR="root" ;ps  -ef|grep $USR|awk '{ print $1" Some word "$2 }'
```

you can substitute the value of USR with another user.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 ps -u user
```

to select user's process.

to select field

```
 ps -u archemar -o stime,etime,args
STIME     ELAPSED COMMAND
11:50    03:09:59 sshd: archemar@pts/1
11:50    03:09:59 -bash
14:59       01:04 sshd: archemar@pts/4
14:59       01:04 -bash
```

see `man ps` to get the  various field.

Answer (score 0):

```
user=root
ps -o user= -o pid= -u "$user" | sed 's/[ 0-9]*$/ "some word"&/'
```