# How to interrupt the watch command?

Tags: kill, watch

I have a program which prints some info to stdout and I run it like so:

```
watch -n 0.1 myprogram
```

My problem is that I need `myprogram` to exit cleanly, calling appropriate destructors to release system-wide mutexes. If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then `watch` is killed and `myprogram` isn't given the chance to exit cleanly.

Is there a way to exit `watch` cleanly so that it waits for the child process to finish before returning?

The `man` page simply says:

> **watch** will run until interrupted

Comment: The premise of the question is incorrect. Your program is given a chance to exit cleanly, but it is up to the program to handle SIGINT, just as if you were to run it without `watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question "*Is there a way to exit watch cleanly?*", yes, you can stop a process by sending a signal.

First you need to [find out the process ID (PID) of your running `watch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790895/linux-bash-using-ps-o-to-get-process-by-specific-name). You can do this by name:

```
pidof watch
```

or by user and [How to see process created by specific user in Unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85466/how-to-see-process-created-by-specific-user-in-unix-linux)

```
ps -u ${USER} | grep -i watch | cut -d " " -f 1
```

and then [stop `watch` by sending a signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150282/stop-shell-script-in-background-by-sending-signal) like

```
kill -IT ${PID}
kill -INT $(pidof watch)
```

The second part of your question is then more [about handling signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signals).

Comment: Yes, it was the "handling signals" that I missed.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is just a complicated alternative to pressing CTRL+C. CTRL+C sends SIGINT. Why would you want to do it manually through `kill`? And even sending a signal manually can be done much simpler: `pkill -INT watch`

Comment: @Patrick, maybe one need to send an other signal instead of INT. It is scriptable if necessary, at least it is showing how to do it and one could use the approach in other use cases. One could automate things. Etc...