# Why is top command showing users that the who command is not?

Tags: linux, users, raspberry-pi, top, who

Working on a Raspberry Pi 2, running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

I am simply trying to understand why, when I run the `top` command I can see some users that I cannot see in the `who` command. Here is output of the commands run on the RPi:

```
$ top
top - 12:36:42 up 2 days, 15:19,  2 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.34, 0.27
Tasks: 138 total,   1 running,  73 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.0 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :   949460 total,   354296 free,    62916 used,   532248 buff/cache
KiB Swap:   102396 total,    30972 free,    71424 used.   811488 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
10907 iceman    20   0    6144   3400   1924 S   2.3  0.4   4:05.37 rsync
10876 maverick  20   0    8128   3300   2740 R   1.6  0.3   0:36.49 top
  376 root      20   0  911240   9648   3164 S   0.7  1.0  31:58.38 dockerd
  663 root      20   0  149932   1728   1020 S   0.7  0.2  28:25.48 Xorg
  674 root      20   0  884620   3848   1764 S   0.7  0.4  22:06.18 docker-co


$ who
maverick   pts/0        2018-11-28 11:23 (73.69.181.86)
maverick   pts/1        2018-11-28 11:58 (73.69.181.86)
```

To clarify, I have tried: `who`, `who -u`, `who -l`, `who -p`, `who -a`.

Comment: Because the other users are not logged on, they simply have processes running on the system. Try `man who` you will see that it list only **logged on** users.

Comment: I see now, thank you. With your answer I moved on to `ps  -ef` and others to inspect what users were doing that are **not logged on**. [Reference: How to see process created by specific user in Unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85466/how-to-see-process-created-by-specific-user-in-unix-linux)

Comment: `who` and `w` are only printing in a human-friendly way the content of `/var/run/utmp`. It doesn't matter if those users are logged in or not, or if the programs they were logged in with started a session, or if they had to enter a password, or whatever; it only matters if they ran a program that bothered to write a record to `/var/run/utmp`. For instance, I may run `su - user`, enter a password, etc and `user` will be nowhere to be seen in the output of `w`. But if I run `xterm +ut`, both `who` and `w` will show an extra entry for that "session".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find additional information about your system's command-line tools and their parameters by looking at their "man page" (by running `man who`, for example).

---

From the respective man pages:

> `top` - display Linux processes

> `who` - show who is logged on

While we're at it, there is also:

> `w` - Show who is logged on and what they are doing.

A user is "logged on" when they have performed a "login", that is they have provided a password or key to authenticate to the system, and the system has launched a "session" for them.

As you can see, `who` only lists these login sessions — usually together with what the session is attached to, such as

- an Xserver session (e.g. `:0` for the first graphical session),
- a terminal (`tty`, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>),
- or a pseudo-terminal (`pts`, e.g. for an SSH session, terminal emulator or terminal multiplexer program)

There are other ways to start processes that do not involve a login session, such as

- system services (started by `init`, `systemd`, or whatever your system uses for service startup)
- SSH sessions that did not request a tty device — this usually happens when you give a command directly after the SSH invocation (`ssh example.com rsync …`) instead of requesting an interactive shell (`ssh example.com`)
- starting a process from a login session, but then detaching it from the current shell, and thereby the session (e.g. using `disown`)

---

Tangentially, if you want to know what users exist on the system (both locally configured ones from `/etc/passwd` and any from an external database like LDAP):

```
getent passwd
```

If you also want to know when they last logged in:

```
lastlog
```